# What is comsuming my memory on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have a desktop with 12 gb of ram. Normally it works fine.

Recently, I started having some memory issues that I can't see where it's coming from.

Currently I'm running few applications with a total roughly of 2GB but the task manager shows a total of 94% consumed of my RAM. (2GB doesn't correspond to 94% of my RAM)

There is only one user connected to my machine and I restarted it several times.

Does anyone have an explanation to this please ?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try posting from the detailed view in Task Manager.

Comment: Run Admin Tools, Resource Monitor, make sure the memory line is open and then let it run to get a 15 - 30 minute graph and see if anything else pops out.

Comment: @John I've added the resource monitor.

Comment: @Mark what do you mean by detailed view in Task Manager please ?

Comment: There is 6 GB just in what shows. Lots of browser tabs (close these), Big SQL and Oracle  running.  Also do a full scan for viruses.  When done, restart, do not start anything and you should be under 4 GB total

Comment: Also if after you check everything, you want tons of stuff running, add memory to 32 GB.  I have 16 GB with 3 complete machines running at the same time and still have 7 GB remaining.

Comment: @John adding the memory is not the solution. I started having this problem only few days ago. And ok, assuming 6GB are consumed, it's still not 94%.

Comment: The 6 GB i quoted was just partial because I could not see more. Did you check for viruses, especially if this just started. Viruses could be running things which show up as memory consumed.

Comment: Yes I have just scanned my computer. Couldn't find any viruses

Comment: I would list every app using memory. Use Startup Manager or Autoruns to see what is starting . That is another way memory gets used up.

Comment: The single application by itself is using 2 GB.  Your system is actively using 11 GB based on the number of browser tabs I would guess its being used by legitimate applications.  There is no way your only using 2 GB. of memory since Windows recommendation is more than quadruple that amount.

Comment: @Ramhound which single application you are talking about ? The view I'm showing is sorted from high to low memory usage. Here the biggest ones are SQLdeveloper : 673Mb, Chrome 432Mb, Oracle 411Mb and some 20 to 30 other applications using around 20 to 30Mb. So let's say 1Gb for these applications. The total is around : 2.5Gb. Far from 94% of 12Gb installed

Comment: I have asked you to do two tests to help yourself which I do not think you have done yet.  (1) Restart with no apps running. You should be using 4 GB of memory - the rest free.  (2) Check what is auto-starting (Task Manager Startup Tab). See if a memory hog is running at startup.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton - Resource Monitor indicates that SQLdeveloper is using 2 GB not 673 MB